Can I set CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA globally in Angular 17 without an application module?
I have recently migrated my project to Angular 17 and as part of that upgrade I removed app.module.ts, migrating its configuration to app.config.ts. I also migrated from Material Angular to using some web components.
Currently, I am forced to introduce in every component schemas: schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]. Since I will use these web components in every component I want to include this property globally so that I don't have to write it for every component. If I was using app.module.ts I know that this would have been possible, however in my current configuration I am not sure how to do that.
For reference, here are my two entry files:
main.ts:
import {appConfig} from './app/app.config';
import {bootstrapApplication} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));

app.config.ts:
import {ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom} from '@angular/core';
import {provideRouter} from '@angular/router';

import {routes} from './app.routes';
import {provideHttpClient, withInterceptors} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CookieModule} from 'ngx-cookie';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(CookieModule.withOptions()),
  ],
};


I am looking for a solution that will not make me create an app.module.ts
I tried to see if I could include the "schemas" property in my appConfig object, however that did not work. I also tried searching online for this specific issue but I only found the solution for including it in app.module.ts

Seems like this is currently not supported, but sounds like a reasonable feature which you could request via their issue tracker.

When you use this CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA you are making your application ignore many crucial errors which help you during development, instead just register the web components.
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { createApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ToggleComponent } from './app/toggle/toggle.component';

(async () => {

  const app = await createApplication({
    providers: [
      /* your global providers here */
    ],
  });

  const toogleElement = createCustomElement(ToggleComponent, {
    injector: app.injector,
  });

  customElements.define('my-toggle', toogleElement);

})();

Angular Elements: Web Components with Standalone Components
How to build web components from Angular elements

Your approach is interesting, however this implies that I have an Angular component to register. Spectrum Web Components are not written in Angular, they are framework agnostic. Do you have a workaround for this case? Here is a web component example: https://opensource.adobe.com/spectrum-web-components/components/button/

In addition, from the official documentation I see that CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA allows components with '-' in their name. Is the  development impact significant if I allow this?

@luismicu Yes if you have a typo in your component, or you use Input and output and pass the incorrect types, then you will not be able to see the errors during compilation

So the only viable solution is to go through the JavaScript Web Components definition and convert them to Angular Components to then be able to register them?

@luismicu alll the components need a angular component wRapper, this will have the schema definition and enable users to use the web components freely, basically a wrapper package is needed
